# Get Undefined from a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have variable that assign from a service, and I need real time calculator from the variable's value to fill another variable.

Here's the code

```
$scope.getSubTotalSCTax = function(){
    TableService.checkOut('SubTotal',$scope.DetailMeja.finCheckInID)
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.checkOut = {
            SubTotal:response.SubTotal,
            TaxPercentage:response.TaxPercentage,
            ServiceChargePercentage:response.SCPercentage,
        };
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
};
$scope.getSubTotalSCTax();

$scope.checkOut.ServiceCharge = $scope.checkOut.SubTotal * $scope.checkOut.ServiceChargePercentage / 100;
$scope.checkOut.Tax = $scope.checkOut.SubTotal * $scope.checkOut.TaxPercentage / 100;
```

I always get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'SubTotal' of undefined`
 at this line `$scope.checkOut.ServiceCharge = $scope.checkOut.SubTotal * $scope.checkOut.ServiceChargePercentage / 100;`

*EDIT :
I'm have the `input type="text"` for the Tax Percentage and Service Charge Percentage.
And I need to re-Calculate everytime the Tax Percentage Or Service Charge Percentage change their value

*EDIT2 :
re-Calculate problem solved with `ng-change` event and call a function that run `re-Calculate` function

Comment: It seems `TableService.checkOut('SubTotal'` is an AJAX request and the `$scope.checkOut = {` is being assigned in the callback but you are trying to access it even before the value is set in the callback.

Comment: `$scope.checkOut` is defined when `.then` is invoked..It is `undefined` before that..

Comment: but I triggred `$scope.getSubTotalSCTax();` before I call `$scope.checkOut.SubTotal`.. Are you have any solution ?? :)

Comment: The request is asynchronous so even if you called the function before accessing the variable, the variable itself it set afterwards.

Comment: Set `$scope.checkOut = {};` before `$scope.getSubTotalSCTax = function(){`

Comment: It works.. But.. The `$scope.checkOut.ServiceCharge` and `$scope.checkOut.Tax` Remains empty...

Comment: I have added answer please check this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to account for the fact that `TableService.checkout` runs asynchronously. It won't have called the `then` callback until after the rest of your code has evaluated.

You can solve this by returning the promise.

```
$scope.getSubTotalSCTax = function(){
  var promise = TableService.checkOut('SubTotal',$scope.DetailMeja.finCheckInID);

  promise.then(function(response){
    // ...
  });

  return promise;
};
```

Then chaining another `then` onto the promise when you call the method.

```
$scope.getSubTotalSCTax().then(function() {
  $scope.checkOut.ServiceCharge = $scope.checkOut.SubTotal * $scope.checkOut.ServiceChargePercentage / 100;
  $scope.checkOut.Tax = $scope.checkOut.SubTotal * $scope.checkOut.TaxPercentage / 100;
});
```

Comment: whoa.. Finnaly. Thanks for your solution.. It works !

Comment: I'm sorry, It works, but It can't calculate when I'm change the value on Tax Percentage from the textBox

Comment: You haven't included any code related to a textBox, so that's not too surprising.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope.getSubTotalSCTax = function() {
    return TableService.checkOut('SubTotal', $scope.DetailMeja.finCheckInID)
};

$scope.getSubTotalSCTax().then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $scope.checkOut.ServiceCharge = response.SubTotal * response.SCPercentage / 100;
    $scope.checkOut.Tax = response.SubTotal * response.TaxPercentage / 100;

}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: Sorry.. Still Can't re-calculate the Tax And Service Charge